# SQL - Agrupar varios Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, null

Quisiera unir en una sola consulta dos Count que los tengo por separados.

En la primera consulta, mirando datos en vivos, obtengo la cantidad de los datos que están llegando nulos.
Esta es la sentencia.

```
SELECT IOServer.ComputerName as [Computer Name], IOServer.ApplicationName as [Application Name], Topic.Name as [Access Name], COUNT(*) as Nulos
FROM AnalogTag, EngineeringUnit, Tag, v_Live, Topic, IOServer, IODriver
WHERE
Tag.TagName not like '%sys%'
AND v_Live.Value is Null
AND Tag.TagName = AnalogTag.TagName
AND tag.tagname = v_live.TagName
AND AnalogTag.EUKey = EngineeringUnit.EUKey
AND Topic.TopicKey = Tag.TopicKey
AND IOServer.IOServerKey = Topic.IOServerKey
AND IOServer.IODriverKey=IODriver.IODriverKey
GROUP BY Topic.Name,IOServer.ComputerName,IOServer.ApplicationName
ORDER BY IOServer.ComputerName, Topic.Name
```

En la segunda consulta obtengo la cuenta de la cantidad total de todos los datos en vivos.

```
SELECT IOServer.ComputerName, IOServer.ApplicationName, Topic.Name as AccessName, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM AnalogTag, EngineeringUnit, Tag, v_Live, Topic, IOServer, IODriver
WHERE
Tag.TagName not like '%sys%'
AND Tag.TagName = AnalogTag.TagName
AND tag.tagname = v_live.TagName
AND AnalogTag.EUKey = EngineeringUnit.EUKey
AND Topic.TopicKey = Tag.TopicKey
AND IOServer.IOServerKey = Topic.IOServerKey
AND IOServer.IODriverKey=IODriver.IODriverKey
GROUP BY Topic.Name,IOServer.ComputerName,IOServer.ApplicationName
ORDER BY IOServer.ComputerName, Topic.Name
```

Lo que necesito haces es mostrar los valores Nulos y al lado su total.
Opción 01
Mostrar solo si tienen valores nulos.

```
ComputerName | ApplicationName | Access Name | Nulos | Totales
Computer02   | aplicación01    | Acces_100   |   2   |    25
```

Opción 02
Mostrar totales y el número de nulos.

```
ComputerName | ApplicationName | Access Name | Nulos | Totales
Computer02   | Aplicación01    | Acces_100   |   2   |   25
Computer1    | Applicacion03   | Acces_205   |   0   |   25
```

El motor es SQL server 2014
Desde ya agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas. Indica exactamente el resultado que quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que con una subconsulta y luego agrupando podrias obtener el resultado, intenta con esto:

```
select 
ComputerName, 
ApplicationName,
Name,
SUM(Nulos) Nulos,
SUM(Unidad) Total
FROM (SELECT 
IOServer.ComputerName, 
IOServer.ApplicationName, 
Topic.Name, 
1 Unidad,
case
    when v_Live.Value is Null then 1
    else 0
end Nulos
FROM AnalogTag, EngineeringUnit, Tag, v_Live, Topic, IOServer, IODriver
WHERE
Tag.TagName not like '%sys%'
AND Tag.TagName = AnalogTag.TagName
AND tag.tagname = v_live.TagName
AND AnalogTag.EUKey = EngineeringUnit.EUKey
AND Topic.TopicKey = Tag.TopicKey
AND IOServer.IOServerKey = Topic.IOServerKey
AND IOServer.IODriverKey=IODriver.IODriverKey) x
GROUP BY ComputerName, 
ApplicationName,
Name
ORDER BY ComputerName, Name
```

Answer (score 3):

Si me permites un poco de cirugía mayor en tu consulta, la idea sería así:

```
SELECT  IOS.ComputerName                                           as [Computer Name], 
        IOS.ApplicationName                                        as [Application Name], 
        T.Name                                                     as [Access Name], 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN V.Value is Null THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)      as Nulos,
        COUNT(1)                                                   as Todos
        FROM AnalogTag A
        INNER JOIN EngineeringUnit E
            ON A.EUKey = E.EUKey
        INNER JOIN Tag TA
            ON TA.TagName = A.TagName
        INNER JOIN v_Live V
            ON TA.tagname = V.TagName
        INNER JOIN Topic T,
            ON T.TopicKey = TA.TopicKey
        INNER JOIN IOServer IOS
            ON IOS.IOServerKey = T.IOServerKey
        INNER JOIN IODriver IOD
            ON IOS.IODriverKey = IOD.IODriverKey
        WHERE TA.TagName not like '%sys%'
        GROUP BY T.Name,
                 IOS.ComputerName,
                 IOS.ApplicationName
        ORDER BY IOS.ComputerName, 
                 T.Name
```

Comentarios

- Es una buena práctica el uso de los **JOIN's explicítos** por sobre los **Implícitos**
- No necesitas dos consultas ya que ambas son fundamentalmente la misma solo cambia la condición de `NULL` en `v_Live.Value`, por lo que puedes resolverlo con una única consulta y cun `COUNT()` condicional.